# What if you delete bfsvc.exe?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Does `bfsvc.exe` start the boot service or `bootmgr`? Most relatedly to my question, what if you delete it? Is it as crucial as `ntoskrnl.exe` or `explorer.exe`?

Answer (score 0):

> Does bfsvc.exe start the boot service or bootmgr? Most relatedly to my
> question, what if you delete it?

See this article below.

If bfcvs.exe is legitimate, it is part of the Windows booting system and should NOT be deleted.

You may wish to do a Full Scan with Windows Defender.

If bfsvc has been replaced with a trojan (virus), allow Windows Defender to quarantine it.

I have a legitimate version of bfsvc.exe in C:\Windows and it is not causing any issue.

There are also versions of bfsvc in WinSXS (for error repair).

[bfsvc.exe](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/bfsvc-exe-is-it-safe-or-a-virus)

> Ideally, bfsvc.exe is the Windows operating system file for the Boot
> File Servicing Utility. It’s vital to your computer’s functioning, but
> that’s only if it’s the legitimate bfsvc.exe.
>
> I added the above clause because while bfsvc.exe should be an
> essential system file, a Trojan horse virus also disguises as this
> file. This virus adds your computer to a ZeroAccess botnet of tens of
> millions of other infected computers around the globe. When you’re
> part of a botnet, remote hackers will use your computer to carry out
> coordinated cyberattacks, such as DDoS.
>
> The issue now is that on the one hand, bfsvc.exe could be a vital
> Windows system file that you shouldn’t delete. On the other hand, it
> could also be a dangerous Trojan virus that you must remove from your
> system.